# How to register ContextMenu for a menu Item

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu, menuitem

i want to open a contextMenu on click of MenuItem. How can i register context menu for options menu item in my activity.
which view can i have to pass in `registerForContextMenu(?view?);` in this case?

this is my menuItem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_change_font"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/pref_font_size_title"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:visible="true"/>
</menu>
```

this is my contextMenu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/font_small"
            android:title="@string/small"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/font_medium"
            android:title="@string/medium"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/font_large"
            android:title="@string/large" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

this is OnCreateMenuItem method

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_font_size, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

this is my OnOptionsItemSelected method

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    } else if(id == R.id.action_change_font){
        // want to open context menu
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725599/how-to-open-the-contextmenu-from-menuitem-android

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: @Ankita this is not the answer of my question. i want to register it with menuItem. how can i get view of menuItem?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @Ankita code added

Answer (score 0):

Move context menu into the root menu like this. Selecting the "Change font" item will automatically open a submenu.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_change_font"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/pref_font_size_title"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:visible="true">

        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item android:id="@+id/font_small"
                    android:title="@string/small"/>
                <item android:id="@+id/font_medium"
                    android:title="@string/medium"/>
                <item android:id="@+id/font_large"
                    android:title="@string/large" />
            </group>
        </menu>

    </item>
</menu>
```

Handle submenu clicks directly in the onOptionsItemSelected method.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    } else if(id == R.id.font_small){
        // Change font to small
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```